# How do I configure a spring aplication to run on app engine?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

This is a spring boot server that will run on Google App engine. However it gives me the exception:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
```

This is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.google.appengine.demos</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-appengine-standard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springboot-appengine-standard</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As far as i know, it is running on jetty because of spring-jetty starter and exclusion of tomcat. I mapped the servlet in web.xml. So according to google's own documentation and a couple other tutorials online, there is no logical reason why this shouldnt work. But as soon as a rest request is made, not deploy, it deploys and runs, but when the request is made it gives that exception i showed previously.

I also have this in the @SpringBootStarter

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloAppEngine extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(HelloAppEngine.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloAppEngine.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe javax.servlet-api is not provided on app engine. Try change scope to compile. Notice, app engine for java11 not provided servlet api. Also check your file src/main/appengine/app.yaml is correct

Comment: Could you share you app.yaml to make a replica?

Comment: What tutorial are you following? I've seen quite a few deprecated versions that probably don't work anymore.

Comment: This issue is caused from dependencies which i'm not sure how to manage. In case you are looking for a decent spring boot GAE tutorial I found these two that vary in the dependencies this one is from[codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot#3) and this one is from [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/quickstart). the offical documentation has the same `artifactId` named `spring-boot-starter-jetty` which might be what you're looking for and can help you find your error.

Comment: Both of these were tested successfully.